# ContextMenu and Hierachicaldatatemplate Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In the MainWindow I have an ObservableCollection of "parent" items.
Every parent, has an ObservableCollection of "device" items.

The first level of my ContextMenu is properly bind to the items of the first Collection. The problem is, for every MenuItem I am getting always the same results (meaning that the datacontext for each MenuItem is always the same "parent"?)

Here is a screenshot, to better understand:

[ContextMenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1khJ5.png)

And here is the XAML code:

```
    <StackPanel.Resources>

        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Parents}" x:Key="Parents"/>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:parent}">
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <Binding>
                    <Binding.Source>
                        <CompositeCollection>
                            <MenuItem Header="ParentStartAll"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="ParentStopAll"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="ParentRestartAll"/>
                            <Separator/>
                            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Childs, Source={StaticResource Parents}}"/>
                        </CompositeCollection>
                    </Binding.Source>
                </Binding>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:device}">
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <Binding>
                    <Binding.Source>
                        <CompositeCollection>
                            <MenuItem Header="StartAll"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="StopAll"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="RestartAll"/>
                            <Separator/>
                            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Processes, Source={StaticResource Parents}}"/>
                        </CompositeCollection>
                    </Binding.Source>
                </Binding>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>


        [...]


    </StackPanel.Resources>


    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}">
        </ContextMenu>
    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, when I try to open the ContextMenu for the second time, it only shows the first level (only the "parents").

Any hints?

Pretty newbie here, so please don't angry if the question is too easy or if I made some ugly mistakes. I have to say it was not easy to manage the binding in the firstplace and I am struggling to get this contextmenu working.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: not even a small hint? as usual, I am not looking for someone to do my homework, just a hint to point to the right direction.

Comment: If you are still looking for an answer, I would consider moving the context menu inside the hierarchical template